# make eclipse-project in stack

Tags: ros, stack, eclipse

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi !

I'm a beginner in ros, and I'm trying to develop ROS code using Eclipse.

My question is, recently I have created a repository in github with a ros stack, and inside of this ros stack I have some packages. I would like to import all the stack like a single project, but I'm not able to do a "make eclipse-project" with the stack.

So I can import as a project all the packages and it work perfectly but I don't know if is possible to import all the stack in one eclipse project.

Any one have done this ?

How do you develop multiple packages using a IDE ? you open a project for each package and put dependencies between them ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9930/make-eclipse-project-in-stack/) by [Catotaku](https://answers.ros.org/users/516/catotaku/) on ROS Answers with karma: 163 on 2011-05-09

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Asomerville](https://answers.ros.org/users/351/asomerville/) on 2011-05-12**:
Btw, could you reword your title/headline into a question? It makes the issue clearer when browsing headlines, and fits the question answer model better.

**Comment by [Felix Endres](https://answers.ros.org/users/113/felix-endres/) on 2011-05-09**:
The idea of packages is, that they are relatively independent of each other. Usually they only interface either by linking of libraries or by ros messages. What advantage would it be, to have a single eclipse project? See also: http://www.ros.org/wiki/Stacks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I use Eclipse and to work on several packages at once, I simply make projects for each individually, and open them into my workspace. Eclipse will find and open all project under any directory you give it which works well for a stack if you've made Eclipse projects for each with `make eclipse-project`

AFAIK, neither Eclipse nor CMake can auto-detect other eclipse projects to link them automatically

---

Originally posted by [Asomerville](https://answers.ros.org/users/351/asomerville/) with karma: 2743 on 2011-05-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [markpitchless](https://answers.ros.org/users/1668/markpitchless/) on 2012-04-27**:
$ cat ~/bin/make-eclipse-all
#!/bin/bash

basedir=$(pwd)
for file in $(find . -name 'CMakeLists.txt'); do
makedir=$(dirname "$file")
echo $file - $makedir
cd "$basedir"
cd "$makedir"
make eclipse-project
done

**Comment by [markpitchless](https://answers.ros.org/users/1668/markpitchless/) on 2012-04-27**:
$ cat ~/bin/make-eclipse-all
#!/bin/bash

basedir=$(pwd)
for file in $(find . -name 'CMakeLists.txt'); do
makedir=$(dirname "$file")
echo $file - $makedir
cd "$basedir"
cd "$makedir"
make eclipse-project
done

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm not using eclipse, but I'm guessing that the dependencies should still be resolved by rosmake called via eclipse.
You can have a look at this page: [ROS IDEs](http://www.ros.org/wiki/IDEs)

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2011-05-10

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

(This is really a comment to add to Asomerville's answer but I don't have the Karma to edit the post and the comment want format the script nicely).

I have this script to create all the project files for a workspace/stack. Just cd to the root of the workspace and run to have make eclipse-project run on all packages.

```
 $ cat ~/bin/make-eclipse-all 
 #!/bin/bash
 basedir=$(pwd)
 for file in $(find . -name 'CMakeLists.txt'); do
     makedir=$(dirname "$file")
     echo $file - $makedir
     cd "$basedir"
     cd "$makedir"
     make eclipse-project
 done
```

---

Originally posted by [markpitchless](https://answers.ros.org/users/1668/markpitchless/) with karma: 390 on 2012-04-27

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2012-06-06**:
This script works great although I can't tell what is the poster's name...anyway thanks a lot!